# Angular router.navigate not working from parent component to child component

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ui-router, router

in my case i navigated from availableComponent --to-->  reserveComponent successfully . but when i try navigate to confirmComponent , riuter.navigate not working

i try redirect to  confirmComponent by this code:

```
onContinuePayment() {
    // this.router.navigated = false;
    debugger
    this.router.navigate(['flight/confirm'], {
      queryParams: {
        source: 'g'
      }
    });
  }
```

and my routing module is :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '' , component: FlightComponent,
    children: [
        {
          path: 'available',
          component: AvailableFlightsComponent
        } ,
        {
          path: 'reserve',
          component: ReserveFlightComponent
        } ,
        {
          path: 'confirm',
          component: ReserveConfirmComponent
        } ,
        {
          path: 'reserve-confirm',
          component: ReserveConfirmationComponent
        }
      ]
  }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

but it not work

Answer (score 0):

```
path: '' , component: FlightComponent
```

should be

```
path: 'flight' , component: FlightComponent
```

Your intention here is to set up routes for the urls `/flight/{child}`, where `{child}` is one of `available`, `reserve`, `confirm`, etc.

Making the assumption that you also want flight component to be served for the url `/flight`, assigning the path `flight` to the parent route will then mean the child routes effectively inherit the `/flight/` prefix for their paths.

If you don't want the flight component to be associated with the url `/flight`, then you could insert a component-less route inbetween flight and its children:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '' , component: FlightComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'flight', children: [
        {
          path: 'available',
          component: AvailableFlightsComponent
        } ,
        {
          path: 'reserve',
          component: ReserveFlightComponent
        } ,
        {
          path: 'confirm',
          component: ReserveConfirmComponent
        } ,
        {
          path: 'reserve-confirm',
          component: ReserveConfirmationComponent
        }
      ] }    
    ]
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
this.router.navigate(['/flight/confirm'], {
  queryParams: {
    source: 'g'
  }
});
```

Regards.

Comment: router.navigate would be happy with `['flight/confirm']`, if the parent route were configured with the path 'flight'.

Comment: @armandyjoe this.router.navigate(['/flight/confirm'] is not work

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this one**

```
this.router.navigate(['confirm'], {
      queryParams: {
        source: 'g'
      }
    });
```

Comment: where did you added router outlet?

Comment: router outlet exists in flight component